# What does the z component of ncurses mouse events represent?

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

From ncurses.h

```
typedef struct
{
    short id;       /* ID to distinguish multiple devices */
    int x, y, z;    /* event coordinates (character-cell) */
    mmask_t bstate; /* button state bits */
}
MEVENT;
```

What does the z coordinate represent?

Comment: I don't know how to use ncurses, but I suppose it's reserved for futur extensions. Did you try ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the `curs_mouse` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/curs_mouse):

> The *z* member in the event structure is not presently used.  It is
> intended for use with touch screens (which may be pressure-
> sensitive) or with 3D-mice/trackballs/power gloves.

Also, if you search [`lib_mouse.c` in the ncurses source code](https://github.com/mirror/ncurses/blob/91e462de27aeecd5b1c8965a6dba078f7a438003/ncurses/base/lib_mouse.c) for `->z` and `.z`, you will find that it is only ever set to zero.